# How clear all line in text file and write new string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write this code but not clear text file:

```
        File.WriteAllBytes(string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"), "\\Engine\\TextFile1.txt"), new byte[0]);          
        sr = new StreamWriter(string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"), "\\Engine\\TextFile1.txt"));
        foreach (var item in txtHtmlCode.Content.Split('\n'))
        {
            sr.Write(item + "\n");
        }
        sr.Close();
```

I use this code for clear file but not do it:

```
        StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(string.Concat(Server.MapPath("/"), "\\Engine\\TextFile1.txt"));
        sr.Flush();
        sr.Close();
```

I want clear text file and write new string in this file.What should I do?
how to overwrite text file?

Comment: Instead of `string.Concat` use `System.IO.Path.Combine`

Comment: Why not just overwrite the file with a new empty one?

Comment: I cant do it! because access denied to create new file

Comment: how to overwrite text file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clear and write to text file use this code.

```
string path="Your file Path";
File.WriteAllText(path, String.Empty);
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
tw.WriteLine("Your String!");
tw.Close();
```

And to overwrite text file use this code.

```
string path="Your file Path";
var myFile = File.Create(path);
myFile.Close();
```

Answer (score 7):

I would simply use [`System.IO.File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
String path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/"), "Engine", "TextFile1.txt");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (path, txtHtmlCode.Content);
```

This overwrites the file if it exists, otherwise it will be created.

Comment: @shahroz: ?? _"I want clear text file and write new string in this file"_ What do you really want?

Comment: I read text file in to the textbox . I edit the textbox(Add,remove,delete) string.I need code to replace text file with textbox string.

Comment: @shahroz Which is what this answer does... (but where it says `contents` use `txtHtmlCode.Content`)

Comment: txtHtmlCode.Content is ajax toolkit.txtHtmlCode.Content send you string.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to *rewrite* the file:

```
  File.WriteAllText(@"C:\MyFile.txt", "MyText");
```

If you want to *edit* the file, i.e. change line(s):

```
  var target = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
    .Select(line => line) //TODO: put your actual edit here
    .ToList(); // In order to prevent access problems

  File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt", target);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
File.WriteAllText(filepath, String.Empty);
```

Here you need to provide your filepath and we are going to replace everything with space, after this you can write new text in file everytime.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to remove content from an existing file (this is a limitation present in all the file systems that I know of, nothing to do with .NET). You will have to create the file again, overwriting the old one.

Answer (score 1):

```
IRandomAccessStream stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.AllowOnlyReaders);

stream.Size = 0; // clear the existing content

using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream.AsStreamForWrite()))
{                        
    foreach (...)
    {
        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(...)                           
    }
    await streamWriter.FlushAsync(); 
}

stream.Dispose();
```